# Issue with compiling scss in PhpStorm - Permission issue?

Tags: permissions, sass, phpstorm, compass

I'm having issues compiling my scss files through PhpStorm with compass. Up until recently I've had no issues, if anything I've been having issues since I updated to Yosemite.

I get a very general error of:

> /usr/bin/compass compile
>   /Users/[USER]/Documents/Work/[COMPANY]/Websites/[PROJECT FOLDER]
>   /Users/[USER]/Documents/Work/[COMPANY]/Websites/[PROJECT
>   FOLDER]/scss/style.scss 
>   Individual stylesheets must be in the sass
>   directory.

I've ruled out bad paths/links as I have brought over working projects from my work environment to my home environment. I have created another user on my computer and been able to work with the same projects without issue. I then deleted my original user, created another one with the same name, and no I can now it's back to not working again. So it seems the issue lays in with user?

I've repaired disk permissions via disc utility and reset home directory permissions and ACLs through the reset password tool in recovery mode.

Prior to these tries I uninstalled and installed compass and sass gems

Versions:

```
Mac OS X 10.9.5
PhpStorm 7.1.3
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
rubygems-update (2.4.1)
sass (3.4.11)
```

Here is my file watcher:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Compass issue - https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1769. See the comments in this issue for possible workarounds

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I am note seeing a sound solution. I've downgraded to 1.0.0 without luck. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the register in the paths in `config.rb`. I had the same issue until I placed capital letters where they needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I found that with my set up, it was using a config.rb with the incorrect paths specified. So say you have a file path like this:

```
styles
|--css
|  '--styles.css
|--scss
|  |--styles.scss
|  '--config.rb
```

Then in you config.rb you need to call out the correct paths to those files. In this case i ended up with:

```
...
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "."
sass_path = File.expand_path("..", __FILE__)
...
```

Once i had fixed there paths, the file compiled correctly.

Also I'm not sure if i'm seeing your configuatings in phpStorm correctly, but you need to make sure that when setting up the watcher you are setting up `compass sass` and not just a `sass` watcher as pointed out [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235412/phpstorm-9-and-compass-invalid-option-no-cache)