# PhpStorm 9 and Compass: invalid option --no-cache

Tags: phpstorm, compass-sass

- I have updated my system PATH variable to include `C:/Ruby193/bin/`
- I have checked *Enable Compass Support* in the settings
- I have set *Compass executable file* to `C:\Ruby193\bin\compass`
- I have set *Config path* to my project's `config.rb` file.

When I save a change in any .scss files, Compass tries to run, and I get this:

```
cmd.exe /D /C call C:/Ruby193/bin/compass.bat --no-cache --update example.scss:example.css
Error: invalid option: --no-cache

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure where `--no-cache` is coming from, or what the issue is.

Running Compass 1.0.3 and PhpStorm 9.0.2 on Windows 8

Comment: Is that an output produced by File Watcher?

Comment: This shows up in the Run tab under `Run > Output`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running Compass with Sass command line options - thus the problem. When creating a watcher, please make sure to choose 'Compass SCSS', not 'SCSS'. Or, change your watcher settings accordingly, like

```
Program: C:/Ruby193/bin/compass.bat
Arguments: compile
Working directory: $ProjectFileDir$
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/stylesheets
```

Settings above assume that you have your **config.rb** located in project root folder, and `css_dir = "stylesheets"`